# Geoserver / SLD multiline lables not working?

Tags: geoserver, sld

for several hours Im trying to create a multiline label for a line.
  I use Geoserver 2.5, the line is in postGIS, the style is very simple :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor 

xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">   <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>Borders_1fe760e8</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
          <sld:Name>Borders_1fe760e8</sld:Name>
          <sld:Title>Borders</sld:Title>
          <sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
          <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
            <sld:Rule>
              <sld:Name>rule1</sld:Name>
              <sld:Title>Title 1</sld:Title>
              <sld:Abstract>-</sld:Abstract>
              <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:LineSymbolizer>
              <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                <Label>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Name_1</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]><ogc:PropertyName>Name_2</ogc:PropertyName>
                </Label>
                <sld:Font>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Tahoma</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">16</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Font>
                <sld:LabelPlacement>
                  <sld:PointPlacement>
                    <sld:AnchorPoint>
                      <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                      <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                    </sld:AnchorPoint>
                    </sld:PointPlacement>
                </sld:LabelPlacement>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:VendorOption name="followLine">true</sld:VendorOption>
              </sld:TextSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
          </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>   </sld:NamedLayer> </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

yet I am unable to see the lables 1 and 2 on two lines - they always end up on the same line.
  I tried :

- SLD - CDATA with line break (as seen above)
- SLD - CDATA with `<BR>` tag
- SLD - use only one field, POSTGIS field value with \n (value1\nvalue2)
- SLD - use only one field, POSTGIS field value with `<br>` tag (value1`<br>`value2)

and many other permutations of above, i copy-pasted the code, typed it, used geoserver style editor, typed it manually into xml file directly on the server,  but I wasnt able to produce two line label. I did try all the tricks I was able to find via google.

What am I doing wrong ? Or is it some known Geoserver bug ?

Comment: I have an SLD that works fine for me on geoserver 2.5

Comment: Can you please share ? or is it same as I already tried ?

Answer (score 2):

Here some snippets of my SLD on geoserver 2.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

--header

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

--Rule

```
<Rule>
      <Name>Rule 1</Name>
      <Title>title</Title>
      <Abstract>theme</Abstract>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>120000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>nome_1</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
       ]]> (<ogc:PropertyName>nome_2</ogc:PropertyName>)
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
        </Font>
```

--vendor options

```
        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">20</VendorOption>
      </TextSymbolizer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer to my question

http://ehc.ac/p/geoserver/mailman/message/31520843/

it is NOT POSSIBLE to do multiline label with   `<sld:VendorOption name="followLine">true</sld:VendorOption>` :( Disabling this option and using `sld:LabelPlacement` makes it work, but the label is not following the line.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with some CDATA and a zero-width space, like this;

```
            <se:Label>
                <ogc:PropertyName>region_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
                <![CDATA[​
]]>
                <ogc:PropertyName>population_change_count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
```

What you can't see above is the zero-width space character immediately after the `CDATA[`. Search 'copy zero width space to clipboard' to help you.